# Can't write to file with script

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, sh

I have written a script that is supposed to run some commands, reboot my ubuntu server and then after the server boots up, resume operation, and removes the entry from the bash file.

I have been trying for hours to figure out why my script won't write to .bashrc (or any file for that matter). Testing the commands individually works just fine. However, when run through my script nothing is written to the file. At this point I am stumped and would really like a fresh pair of eyes to help as I am sure the reason is silly and probably something I am missing. This would be my first script so sorry if this ends up being a stupid question. I put the "sudo reboot command in a comment so I won't have to reboot each time.

The script's name is test.sh and is run from ~/ . I hope this is clear and I didn't miss anything.

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Script initiating"

#condition for script to run after reboot, created later on
if [ ! -f /var/run/bootflag ]; then
        echo "First run"
        script="bash ~/test.sh"
        #this will add the script in the bash file so it will be ran on next boot
        echo "$script" >> ~/.bashrc

        echo "bash entry added"
        #creating flag file to check if this is a second run
        sudo touch /var/run/bootflag
        echo "Flag created"
        echo "Rebooting..."
        #sudo reboot
else
        echo "resuming script..."
        echo "cleaning up..."
        #remove the bash entry by replacing it with a space
        sed -i '/bash/d' ~/.bashrc


        echo "bash entry removed"
        #remove the boot flag
        sudo rm -f /var/run/bootflag

        echo "bootflag removed"
        echo "running commands post-reboot"
        #commands here
        echo "script exiting"
fi
```

Comment: When are you looking?

Comment: after running once, I run 
`cat ~/.bashrc`
and check the end of the file

Comment: Use `set -x ` to see what the script does

Comment: Note that `"bash /test.sh"` is running a different script in the root directory

Comment: I corrected that, and I understand how it would result in the script not running post reboot. But still the main issue remains. I added `set -x` before and after the echo command that writes in the file but I don't see any difference when running the command on it's own and piped with `set -x` .

Comment: If you do "echo xxx >>~/.bashrc" and then "tail ~/.bashrc" does that work?

Comment: Yeah, that's what's buffling meI I copied the commands from the script and ran them individually and they produce the result I want. But if ran the script nothing is written to the file. If I manually add something, nothing is removed from the file either when running the scipt twice.

Comment: How are you executing this on boot in the first place?  And maybe you should edit the aforementioned `/test.sh != ~/test.sh` into the question to make it easier on other readers ...

Comment: I read that one way to do it is to add the script execution command in the .bashrc file. i then remove it so it won't run on every boot. Thanks for the suggestion, I edited the question.

Comment: Am I reading that right: `script="bash ¬/test.sh"`.  What's that codepoint 172, #o254, #xac doing there??  Should that maybe be a twiddle...??

Comment: I noticed this and made the change from teamviewer so it appeared as that. I am using a tilde in the script. However, tilde or not, the script should be able to execute the commands regardless. My issues is that commands executed one by one in the terminal work, but when combined in the script they don't.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out.

Because I was running the script with sudo, the script would take the relative path `~/.bashrc` for the root user. The script was working fine all along, I was just looking at my user's .bashrc and was expecting things to appear, when all along the root user's .bashrc file was being written in.

I used `sudo` **inside** the script for all elevated commands and run the script normally without `sudo` and there it is, working as expected.

As I thought, this was beyond silly after all. At least I learned something today.

Thank you all for taking the time to reply and help, I really appreciate it.